# bing maps not working for Windows Store app

Tags: windows-8, bing-maps

Hi I am developing an windows store app using Bing Map SDK, but the app doesn't show the map but instead shows stop screen just like it should for unsupported regions even after I updated the HomeRegion to US and Culture to en-US.

```
<Maps:Map Credentials="<key>" Margin="0,-10,0,10" HomeRegion="US" Culture="en-US" />
    </Grid>
```

Can someone tell me what am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either do this in XAML

```
HomeRegion="US"
```

Or in code as

```
MyMap.HomeRegion = "US";
```

[**Here is the list of supported regions in Bing Map.**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj670541.aspx)

Comment: @whihathac Run the app again... At first it wasn't working on my system too.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the HomeRegion and Culture attributes. I use the map in my app according to http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/03/06/bing-maps-for-winrt-xaml.aspx and works without a problem

Comment: THanks Igor, but i need those attributes as i am in India region and need to override those values.

Comment: Hi @whihathac have you succeeded using bing map for India region, am also trying to do the same, can you please tell me the solution for that.thanks in advance.